# Getting Birthdate of person from Wikipedia using Javascript

Tags: javascript, wikipedia

I want to get a birthdate from Wikipedia using Javascript. But the following code not working for me please help!

Code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  $.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&titles=Albert_Einstein&format=json", function(rawdata){   
   
  
var rawstring =JSON.stringify(rawdata);
  
  
data =JSON.parse(rawstring); 
console.log(data);

  alert(data.birth_date);
  
  });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any error in the browser's development console?  What specifically happens when you debug?  In the browser's development tools, what does the AJAX response contain?

Comment: There is only one hit for `birth_date` in the response... And it isn't a json key. It is a part of the string inside `data.query.pages.736.revisions.*` -- Paste the response in [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) for fun.

Comment: Don't get it from wikipedia. Get if from [wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q937#P569).

Comment: You cannot rely on the format on Wikipedia to be the same on all pages or to not change over time, but if you have to scrap it from there then you'd better get either the [Wikitext source of the page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein?action=raw) or the [rendered content HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein?action=render) (for the last one view the source HTML after clicking the link)